# How should I relate Service Fabric Actors together?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a number of Actors which represent a single physical object (a IoT device).

On reviewing our code base we sometimes pass in an existing ActorReference into other Actors and other times we create a new proxy object.

I would have assumed that passing in a existing Actor Reference is more performant but I'm worried about side-effects so creating a new proxy object would seem lower risk.

What are the pro's and con's of each approach and what should I consider when making a decision on which approach to use ?

Comment: Will agree with @MaGu — there is no difference as a proxy object have to be created in both ways. So the only question is serialization. If you will pass only actor id, it will be even more efficient than ActorReference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From researching a decompiled source code it seems to me using ActorReference.Bind and ActorProxy.Create is nearly equal:

```
public object Bind(Type actorInterfaceType)
{
    return ActorProxy.DefaultProxyFactory.CreateActorProxy(actorInterfaceType, this.ServiceUri, this.ActorId, this.ListenerName);
}

public static TActorInterface Create<TActorInterface>(ActorId actorId, string applicationName = null, string serviceName = null, string listenerName = null) where TActorInterface : IActor
{
    return ActorProxy.DefaultProxyFactory.CreateActorProxy<TActorInterface>(actorId, applicationName, serviceName, listenerName);
}
```

So there are no differences neither in reliability nor in performance.

`ActorReference` supports serialization so it seems more suitable for passing between actors.

Answer (score 0):

Passing ActorReference is better and recommended approach as it allows you to create the ActorProxy with a custom ActorProxyFactory on the receiving side. If an actor is passed as an interface the de-serialization process uses the default actor proxy factory to bind the reference to the proxy and provide the proxy object to the receiving method.